# How to approve multi-authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hi m working on Laravel multi-auth which is working fine, the admin redirects to admin page and user redirects to home page but I wants that if the user isn't approved then it shouldn't login and see the error "you can login after 24hr after your account will be approved"

I add this code in admin middleware but itsn't working:

```php
if (auth()->check() && $request->user()->status == 0) {
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}else{
    return redirect('login')->with('flash_message_error','You can  login after approval');
}
```

admin middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->check() && $request->user()->admin == 0) {
        return redirect()->guest('home');
    }        
    return $next($request);
}
```

Routes:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/home', function(){
        if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
            return view('home');
         }else {
             $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
             return view('adminhome', $users);
         }
    });
});
```

user model:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin',
];
```

this id db migration:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I just wants that when a user register then it should wait until the approved column in database becomes 1 manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `Auth/LoginController` add below methods

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
class LoginController extends Controller
{

 protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['status'] = 1;
    return $credentials;
}


 protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
    // Load user from database

    $user = \App\User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

    // Check if user was successfully loaded, that the password matches
    // and status is not 1. If so, override the default error message.


    if ($user && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $user->status != 1) {

        $errors = [$this->username() => 'you can login after 24hr after your account will be approved'];
    }
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}





}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)     https://ibb.co/k9p1nGk

Comment: it is syntax error , make sure you have proper opening { and closing } brackets in your code

Comment: only add 2 functions in your Login Controller

Comment: Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::login does not exist. this is complete code of current logincontroller  paste.ofcode.org/SFAkA3qaab9kmjKKmUjLSS

Comment: error is saying LoginController is not exists inside `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` folder

Comment: where is your LoginController located , please check

Comment: check namespace in LoginController `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194287/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-saurabh-mistry).